License for a program containing Numpy with PyInstaller
We are developing a program that uses NumPy 2.0. We plan to package this program into an exe with PyInstaller and distribute it.
I ran "pip show numpy" and found a description that included the following library:
Name: libquadmath
Files: numpy.libs\libopenb*.dll
Description: statically linked to files compiled with gcc
Availability: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=libquadmath
License: LGPL-2.1-or-later

This is LGPL. In this case, do we have to impose the various restrictions of the LGPL on our program?　i.e., measures that allow users to perform library replacements, and permission to reverse-engineering. Or can we consider that only NumPy is affected by LGPL, and we have nothing to do with LGPL?


We plan to package this program into an exe with PyInstaller and distribute it.

This is fairly straightforward:

If this DLL file (or anything else compiled from libquadmath) will appear in your PyInstaller distribution in any format (static linking, a separate DLL file, etc.), then you must comply with the LGPL with respect to that object file. This is because you cannot distribute somebody else's object file without a license, and the license you have been offered is the LGPL. The fact that NumPy itself is under a more permissive license is irrelevant - you must comply with the licenses for each and every part of your application, unless you wrote it yourself.

Note however that section 5 of the LGPL does have some limited exceptions for "minor" use of the library. You may want to investigate whether NumPy's usage of this library falls within those parameters.


If you do not include this DLL file in your distribution, then it will (presumably) not work, and it doesn't matter what the license requires, because you're not going to distribute a binary that doesn't work.
If you're compiling for a platform with a package manager (such as some Linux distributions), you might not need to include copies of all object files, because that's the package manager's problem. In that hypothetical, you could argue that your distribution, sans object files, is not a derivative work of the library (which, if correct, would imply that you don't have to comply with the LGPL for that distribution). However, this is a rather controversial position, especially in FOSS spaces, and it is also legally untested in most jurisdictions. The more legally conservative ("safe") assumption is that your application is a derivative work of the library even if the object files are not distributed with it.

As pointed out in the comments, it is rather difficult to do this without complying with the LGPL in the first place, because one of the options for LGPL compliance is simply to use a shared linking mechanism. You may still be affected by the LGPL's other requirements (displaying notices etc.).




Do note that if you do not distribute the LGPL library along with your program then you presumably already enable swapping in a replacement for the LGPL library, which satisfies the LGPL copyleft.

Thank you to Kevin and ecm. For the readers who are concern about the same issue,
here I note that Numpy's dependency to the LGPL library has been removed. https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/2.1.0-notes.html
